# Create a table out of Divs

Tags: html, html-table

I failed to make complex tables out of div's
the max thing is this way .
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

but it help only in simple tables

So can anyone make this as div's :

```
<html> <head> <style> td { TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING: .25em; } </style> </head> 
<body> 
<table width="205" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="3" >1</td><td width="14%" colspan="2" rowspan="2">2</td>
</tr>
<td width="15%">3</td>  <td width="16%">4</td>  <td width="18%">5</td>  
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td height="42" >6</td> <td height="42" >6.1</td>  <td >7</td>  <td >7.1</td> <td >7.2</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td height="42" >6</td> <td height="42" >6.1</td>  <td >7</td>  <td >7.1</td> <td >7.2</td> 
</tr> 

</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a stretch to use that method to rebuild your table because there is no CSS replacement for rowspan and colspan, but it could be done  by floating and clearing the divs instead, or using absolute positioning for some of the content. There are some great tutorials at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/ and http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/ if you're not familiar with these methods.

However, if your table is used to display tabular data, there is no need to convert it to divs as tables are fine for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<div>`'s for tabular data. Use `<table>`.

`<div>`'s should be used for (page) layout purposes, as there is no semantic meaning attached to them and they should not be used in place of `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going with twitter bootstrap.  Here is the site with the forms and tables you can use:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Good luck.